# Getting editor privileges after 500 accepted edits

Tags: discussion, edits, privileges

Why don't we get editor privileges after receiving the [*Copy Editor*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor) badge for 500 accepted edit suggestions?
I guess after 500 accepted edits an user knows very good which edits are useful and which are not. <s>Maybe sometimes even better than an user with 2k+ reps who hasn't even edited 10 questions/answers (no offense).</s>
So IMO it would be fair getting those privileges after 500 accepted edits.
What do you guys think?

---

**Edit**
As many of you guys stated, **yes** there are a few members of this community who are trying to climb up the *reputation ladder* by suggesting *bad* or *dirty* edits. But it is unfair to give the others - which truly try to help - a hard time because of this minority.
On the other hand, how is it possible that this *bad* edits get approved, while everyone get upset about it?

Comment: With all the bad edits that are approved getting to 500 approved edits does not mean they know what to do. Not to mention that with the 1k rep gained from edits they would have already gotten a large chunk of the rep needed to edit anyways.

Comment: @JoeW On the other hand, reaching 2k rep also does not mean they know what to do.

Comment: @Stijn Correct but this is not about changing the edit privilege granted at 2k rep but giving people a chance to earn it earlier.

Comment: @croxy Per your edit, robo-reviewers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

500 Edits is 1k rep, I'm pretty sure that 95% of people with the edit privilege had their 2k before it, 4.99% are just farming reps with poor edits, 0.01% (because we can't say "never") get the badge before the 2k rep.

In fact it may be more "logic" to keep the privilege locked until someone has X positive edit (positive = accepted - rejected) if we would like to be sure to have only good editors. But reps is fair enough, I don't think there is that much of people that get 2k which don't end up read thing on meta, either guidelines or through user's complaint, and learn what they should do or not.

The only recurring problems I saw about edit is those who farm reps and spams the edit queue with poor edits. Of course we can see sometimes complain about a 2k+ edit, but it doesn't seems to happened so often that SE's team need to change something.

Comment: `positive = accepted - rejected` given the state of the edit review queue, this isn't even a good indicator of being a good editor.

Comment: @psubsee2003 don't worry that was just a mere exemple, I don't intend to ask it as a feature :)

Answer (score 21):

Well, given your edit:

> it is unfair to give the others - which truly try to help

I feel obliged to comment on your editing: in the past couple of your edits I clicked through, you leave plenty of room for improvement - yet your edits get accepted. This pretty much proves that someone who can make 500 edits doesn't necessarily know how to make *good* edits.

Lots of your edits entail capitalization (either i -> I or properly capitalizing words at the beginning of sentences), removing salutations and indenting code blocks.

While those are very useful edits, and you're doing a great job at helping Stack Overflow become a place of better quality, an edit (and especially a suggested edit) should fix *all* the issues in a post. A lot of your edits leave lots of other problems in the posts. There's poor paragraphing (lots of arbitrary enters), poor language (missing "the" article) and other weird sentences that don't get fixed, abuse of `inline code` and > quotes, bad tagging, tags in titles, and so on.

So if you want to get to 2K reputation and be able to edit any post: continue what you're doing, but try to fix *everything* in a post you're editing.

Comment: Thank you for this helpfull answer. I realised in the meantime (since I wrote this question) that I acted a little rash and overestimated my editing skills by thinking that I know everything about editing (the ironically fact that my answer got edited 2 mins after I asked, speaks for itself). I'll do my best to follow your tips about what a good edit makes. Again thanks for the constructively help :)