# Too many pending edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I like to improve the site by editing questions and answers, usually to fix formatting issues.

Right now, I can't edit anything. I can't even click the 'edit' button beneath the question or answer. When I mouse over it, I receive a small message that says 'You have too many pending edits'.

Why is there an edit limit in place, especially for users who've had hundreds of edit suggestions approved? And what exactly is the limit?

Comment: I believe the limit is 5. If you have 5 suggested edits pending, you cannot submit any more until some of your old ones get approved. Everything on this website is rate-limited.

Comment: @CodyGray is it also true that it takes some time for approved edits to be "registered"? I made 5 edits on Workplace.SE today and then when I tried to make more I got the error described in this question. 3 edits have been approved but I still get the same error. It might take some time for the scripts to "register" that edits have been approved, just like it takes a few hours before you get awarded a badge? I know that SO is not the same as Workplace.SE, but this type of thing is usually the same across the network.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232), you can have at most [5 pending suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232) per editor.

The purpose of this specific limit is to keep the Suggested Edits queue to a reasonable size. Right now, it's empty, but I have seen it go up to 100 recently. We want reviewers to pay attention to every edit they review, and having fewer posts to review helps. I understand why you think it isn't fair for you, given your edit record, but trust me, there are a lot of people with >100 edits approved who still don't know what they're doing. A related request for giving 'good' editors additional privileges (though more 'radical') was [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336465/4751173).

Comment: just pin reminder of [how do I make good edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)