# What is the maximum time to wait for an edit to be approved or rejected?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I made four edits on October 14th, here are the four links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32942549
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32942548
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32942533
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32942532

I waited 12 days and no one approved or rejected my edit, why? Also, what is the maximum time to wait for an edit to be approved or rejected?

I thought maybe these four edits of mine would never be approved or rejected. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338926/16124033) says that each editor has 5 pending suggested edits. If my four edits are never approved or rejected, I can only edit one more.

Comment: *"Also, what is the maximum time to wait for an edit to be approved or rejected?"* -- I didn't think that such a concept existed. What would you assume should happen once this possible maximum expired? It seems similar to me to the question of what the maximum time is to wait for a posted question to be answered, and so I'm guessing that the answer to your question is similar, that no true maximum exists. But perhaps I'm wrong

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought maybe these four edits of mine would never be approved or rejected

Comment: Perhaps you may be right -- that these four edits may never be approved or rejected. I cannot find anything in the site help docs that discuss this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338926/16124033) says that each editor has 5 pending suggested edits. If my four edits are never approved or rejected, I can only edit one more.

Comment: Ah, that is a different but related issue. A good meta find though, thank you.

Comment: Tag wiki/excerpt edits take forever to review due to the higher reputation requirement to review them and the fact that subject-matter knowledge is sometimes required.

Comment: All 4 have now been reviewed.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't copy and paste the content into a tag wiki, [https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32942532), because it won't be approved. Plagiarizing content for a tag wiki isn't a good start.

Comment: All those edits are worthless or plagiarized & have been rejected. Please learn how the site works & especially how any actions you take work in detail.

Comment: @RyanM That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment. :)

Comment: It's like...half an answer at best.  The other half is that there is no maximum time.  A really good answer would analyze the historical distribution and come up with a distribution of time taken to come up with a more precise answer than my hand-wavey "forever."  Someone in the Meta chat room was doing exactly that, but ran into some issues with edge cases.

Comment: Related: *[What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) edits. A long time to review is a well-known fact about tag wiki edits, and this time the information is provided by [Ryan M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208273/ryan-m) in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/what-is-the-maximum-time-to-wait-for-an-edit-to-be-approved-or-rejected#comment931528_421083):

> Tag wiki/excerpt edits take forever to review due to the higher reputation requirement to review them and the fact that subject-matter knowledge is sometimes required.